# Patch plupload on W7 64 bit

Tags: drupal, windows-7, 64-bit, patch

Some of you may have already read my unanswerd question ["Node Gallery won't show images with Plupload"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791266/drupal-node-gallery-wont-show-images-with-plupload) AND this query is a follow on, because I think if I solve this issue, I will have found the solution to my previous one, as I missed out a step!

I am trying to patch the Plupload module with the [plupload_url.patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/plupload_url.patch), on my laptop running a 64 bit version of Windows 7, but every method I try fails; I think it says the file format isn't supported! So far I have tried GnuWin32 (but I think the clues in the name there), and also the JDiff Plugin for jEdit! So, has anyone been in this situation, or do of a working solution? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I do have a VirtualBox installation of Ubuntu if there are no other alternitives, but I'd prefer not to use that because transfering files from the Guest OS is a pain in the ass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you can't apply the patch and want to know how to do so.

Here's an explanation of path files which may help: http://drupal.org/node/367392

Also see if http://drupal.org/node/14231#comment-22770 and http://drupal.org/node/100527#comment-176252 helps.

Comment: I think I know the various ways to apply patches, but the problem is none of the ways seem to work on my OS. When I tried Git, it gave me an error, and when I went to download UnxUtils, I found that I could only download the Update zip and I recieved a 403 error when I tried to download the main file! As a last resort on this OS, I had a look at the files to attempt to do it manually, but it seemed awfully confusing, and to me something didn't look quite right - so I'm begining to think it is the patch at fault, rather than me!...

Comment: ...I would very much appreciate it if somebody could provide a link to a plupload module that has already been patched! Meanwhile, I will have to see if I have any success with my Ubuntu virtual machine!

Comment: @Andy: you're right, I looked into the code and I can't see where it fits in though the patch file you found is relatively old and may have already been committed to the code and then changed again since.